# What are the downsides of running DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging Method in production?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

What are the downsides of running DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging in a production environment?

It seems feasible to run this conditionally during development, for example: `options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(builder.Environment.IsDevelopment());`
But logging parameters to debug issues happening on production seems like a good way to speed up the development of fixes.

However, Microsoft notes:

> You should only enable this flag if you have the appropriate security measures in place based on the sensitivity of this data.

I'm trying to contextualize what the negative consequences are.

- Does this include account credentials, API keys, account numbers or other sensitive data?
- Where is this data logged?
- How much data is logged?
- Is there a way to only log query parameters when an exception is logged?
- Are there any performance consequences?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you already nailed it. Logging table data in producton is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [same documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.enablesensitivedatalogging?view=efcore-7.0) you quoted also specifies:

> This can include the values assigned to properties of your entity instances, parameter values for commands being sent to the database, and other such data.

What that data might include depends on what data your app stores and uses in the database.

> I'm trying to contextualize what the negative consequences are.

If you have [Protected Health Information](https://www.hhs.gov/answers/hipaa/what-is-phi/index.html#:%7E:text=PHI%20stands%20for%20Protected%20Health,with%20respect%20to%20that%20information.) or [Payment Card Industry](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/)-protected data, for example, there are rules about how you store and transfer that kind of data, and how you control access to that data. In Europe, [GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/) regulates how you store and use the private data of people using a web service. Even if your data doesn't fall under any of those regulations, there are plenty of privacy concerns around much of the data stored in databases.

A company can have all kinds of access controls in place to ensure that only specific services can access the database, and only specific users can see the data through those services. But if a service includes sensitive data in their diagnostic logs, and those logs are available to developers, that can represent a back-door into all kinds of sensitive data.

> Does this include account credentials, API keys, account numbers or other sensitive data?

The question is: Do you use Entity Framework to insert or query data with account credentials, API keys, account numbers, etc.? If so, then yes.

> Where is this data logged?

Wherever you configure it to get logged via Microsoft.Extensions.Logging. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/ for details.

> How much data is logged?

The verbosity of logs can be configured via Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, but you should probably assume anything you store in your database or include in queries to your database could show up there. Specifics may change over time, as you update your Entity Framework package.

> Is there a way to only log query parameters when an exception is logged?

I don't know. It's likely that if you set Entity Framework logs to Error level in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging configuration, you'll only get data logged when errors occur. But in many of the use cases I mention earlier, that data is just as sensitive when an error occurs as it is under ideal conditions.

Instead, consider catching exceptions around your database calls, and wrap those exceptions in new exceptions that add non-sensitive context which you think might be helpful in diagnosing exceptions: things like internal ID values. Then, when the exception ultimately gets logged, it'll have enough data to help you find the problem without putting sensitive data in your log file.

> Are there any performance consequences?

By logging more data, there will be a slight hit to performance, but it probably won't be a defining consideration in deciding when to include this data.

## Summary

In my experience, the vast majority of issues can be diagnosed without knowing specific details about the actual production data being used. The risks associated with logging production data *en masse* far outweigh the benefits you're likely to derive. It's fine to leave this enabled in dev and staging environments where you're not using real, sensitive data, but generally not a good idea in production.